# Troubleshooting Intermittent Timeouts

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, timeout

Apologies for the vagueness of this question but I am pretty confused as to where to start.

The Centos server in question is randomly timing out. I received the following from our server provider and am currently awaiting a response from them to see if they can provide any further information.

This is all I have to go on at the moment:

**Details: CRITICAL - Socket timeout after 10 seconds**

Not sure exactly what I should be looking for in order to fix the problem, I have however noticed that I can fix the issue by manually restarting Apache if only for 30 minutes or so.

From my limited knowledge I would hazard a guess that its an Apache issue as all the websites on the server go down at the same time but I can still ping and connect to it via SSH without any issues.

I'm pretty stumped in terms of what I should be looking out for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Output of apachectl -V incase its of any use:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct 16 2014 14:48:21
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Noticed the generic Apache log file is full of this:

```
script '/var/www/vhosts/default/www/country.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable debug on your server and provide the logs? The apache log you have provided is not related to the timeout issue.